# create element on the fly and append a existing element to this, with using jquery

Tags: jquery

my existing  code as follows

```
$('#'+ContainerId).find('img').each(function(){
    // ...
});
```

I want to crate a div element on the fly and append this existing img to this new created div element.
Result must be like this which I want

```
<div style="text-align:center"><img src=".." /></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [*wrap()*](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/), and you don't even need *each()*:

```
$('#'+ContainerId).find('img').wrap('<div style="text-align:center"></div>');
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/WyXFb/**

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<div/>', {
    css:   {
        'text-align':   'center'
    }
}).append($('#'+ContainerId).find('img'));
```

Ref.: [$()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)